# How can I edit/see the content of a catalog driver file in a human readable format?

Tags: drivers

A digitally signed catalog file (.cat) can be used as a digital signature for an arbitrary collection of files included in a driver package. A catalog file contains a collection of cryptographic hashes. Each hash corresponds to a file that is included in the collection.

I'm sure there is a way to do what I need: for example, look at the 5th image of the following [link](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/)

The image example would suggest to right click on a .cat file and choose the properties option to show the tabs of the pic, but this is not working on Windows 7 Pro, Windows XP Pro sp3 and Windows 8.1 even for files inside C:\windows\system32\catroot\ directory.

How can I edit/see the content of a .cat driver file in a human readable format?

Comment: If the .cab file only contains hash values, then those values cannot be reversed, for obvious reasons.  Since you don't indicate what else, besides the hash values are contained in the .cab files (and I don't feel like looking it up), you should supply that information.  Its worth pointing out that a .cab file is a specialized archive file, so this means it contains a hash to verify the file isn't corrupt (and it's actually the correct file), and the file itself.  So the simplest way would be to just extract the files.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5273/how-do-you-view-the-contents-of-a-cab-file

Comment: My question is about a driver .cat (Catalog) file, not a .cab (Cabinet) file.

Comment: **Answer:** to see the content of a catalog driver, just double-click on it. Thanks to the author of the linked article for the suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the MakeCat tool to create a catalog file for a driver package.

To create a catalog file, you must first manually create a [Online Catalog](https://dcatalog.com/) Definition File (.cdf) that describes the catalog header attributes and file entries. Once this file is created, you can then run the MakeCat tool to create a catalog file. The MakeCat tool does the following when it processes the .cdf file:

1. Verifies the list of attributes for each file that is listed in the .cdf file.
2. Adds the listed attributes to the catalog file.
3. Generates a cryptographic hash, or thumbprint, of each of the listed files.
4. Stores the thumbprint of each file in the catalog file.